# PHP oci_connect() is working on terminal/Centos server but not on browser

Tags: php, oracle, apache

I am getting error when I trying from browser.

> Warning: oci_connect(): ORA-28759: failure to open file in
> /var/www/myapp/abc.php on line 16
>
> Fatal error: ORA-28759: failure to open file in /var/www/myapp/abc.php on
> line 19

But when running same file from Server terminal as a **root** user > **PHP abc.php** that time oracle database output is coming.

I didn't understand why is running from terminal but not on browser.

I am using PHP7, Apache and Installed Oracle 19c home db.

I am using **oci_connect** to communication with oracle database from PHP code.

---

I think there is some permission issue to my httpd (apahce).

Please give suggestion.

Comment: So when you run the CLI it works and when you run through the browser it does not. Sounds to me like you have a different `php.ini` file configured for the CLI and the Web Server!

Comment: 1. Do a `>php --ini` from the CLI and look at `Loaded Configuration File:` and then 2. Write a `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` script and run that and look again for the `Loaded Configuration File` in that output

Answer (score 0):

- Check that the web server process has access to all the Oracle client libraries and data files.  Since you are using an Oracle home, make sure all the directories have 'other' access permissions set.  Typically user home directories don't have this by default.
- Since the app is running, some libraries are being loaded so maybe permissions are OK? Make sure you have the web server process environment variables the same as those used by your command shell to make sure the same set of Oracle client libraries are being used.  (Do you also have Instant Client installed somewhere, or another Oracle home??).
- The recent common causes of 'ORA-28759: failure to open file' are when Oracle cloud wallets are being used and the sqlnet.ora path to the wallet (the `DIRECTORY=...` bit) is not valid. ​Check the path is OK, or the Oracle Net configuration files are in the default location (and are readable).  Note that with Instant Client 19.14 you can use 1-way TLS so wallets are not always needed, depending on your net configuration.
- I doubt there is a problem with php.ini, since you are obviously able to call OCI8 functions.  The php.ini file doesn't control behaviors of the Oracle Client libraries that are throwing the error.

Update your question with more details about how you are setting the environment and what Oracle configuration files are being used for connecting

Comment: Thank You @christopher-jones for your seggestion.

I Set ENV variable and also set in httpd filie ORACLE_HOME, ORACLE_SID, LD_LIBRARY_PATH, NLS_LANG, TNS_ADMIN 

.Can you suggestion me some command So I can provide you output. 

I am not familiar with CentOS Linux.